# Can BigQuery send a pub/sub message?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I'd like for a BigQuery table to send a pub/sub message anytime the table changes.

Is this possible? I'm not seeing it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: No CDC in BigQuery for now.

Answer (score 5):

BigQuery does not currently have any notifications that it sends directly to Pub/Sub. You can however use events that it sends to Cloud Logging (e.g. for table update) and use a [Cloud Logging Pub/Sub topic sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) to be notified of these. Please see [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/bigquery-cloud-functions-how-to-run-your-queries-as-soon-as-a-new-google-analytics-table-is-17fbb62f8aaa) which outlines the approach.

Comment: This Cloud Logging Pub/Sub topic method OR the current EventArc triggers, both don't send the actual data, correct? Because I needed a event with the inserted/updated/deleted data, to capture data changes... Is there any method to accomplish this?